# dynamic drop down menu for labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a drop down menu displaying 3 options. Once the user selects an option, another drop down menu will display itself based on the choice from the first menu.

The first dropdown(InDiameter):

```
                <label for="innerdiameter"><i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i>1. Inner Diameter:(*)          


                <select id="InDiameter" name="InDiameter">
                  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
                  <option value="Standard(1.0-5.0mm)">Standard(1.0-5.0mm)</option>
                  <option value="Microcuff(0.3-0.75mm)">Microcuff(0.3-0.75mm)</option>
                  <option value="Nanocuffs(56-250μm)">Nanocuffs(56-250μm)</option>
                </select>
                </label>
```

Second dropdown(Standard):

```
<label for="standard"> <br>1a. Inner Diameter for Standard:          


                <select id="Standard" name="Standard">
                  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
                  <option value="1mm">1mm</option>
                  <option value="1.5mm">1.5mm</option>
                  <option value="2mm">2mm</option>
                  <option value="2.5mm">2.5mm</option>
                  <option value="3mm">3mm</option>
                  <option value="3.5mm">3.5mm</option>
                  <option value="4mm">4mm</option>
                  <option value="5mm">5mm</option>
                </select>
                </label>
```

I've tried several js solutions, but none of them have worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you've tried "several js solutions," _post them._

Answer (score 1):

in this case you need some one code of javascript and jquery:

**the html code:**

```
   <label >Select:</label>
   <select id="InDiameter" name="InDiameter" required onchange="miFuncion($(this).val());">
     <option value="N/A">Select</option>
     <option value="Standard">Standard(1.0-5.0mm)</option>
     <option value="Microcuff">Microcuff(0.3-0.75mm)</option>
     <option value="Nanocuffs">Nanocuffs(56-250μm)</option>
  </select>

  <div id="selectStandar" style="display:none;">
  <label>Standard:</label>
    <select id="Standard" name="Standard">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="1mm">1mm</option>
      <option value="1.5mm">1.5mm</option>
      <option value="2mm">2mm</option>
      <option value="2.5mm">2.5mm</option>
      <option value="3mm">3mm</option>
      <option value="3.5mm">3.5mm</option>
      <option value="4mm">4mm</option>
      <option value="5mm">5mm</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="selectMicrocuff" style="display:none;">
    <label>Microcuff:</label>
  <select id="Microcuff" name="Microcuff">
     <option value="1">Microcuff 1</option>
     <option value="2">Microcuff 2</option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

**code jquery and Javascript**

```
  function miFuncion(value_selected){
    if (value_selected=='Standard'){
        $("#selectStandar").show();
      $("#selectMicrocuff").hide();
    }

    if (value_selected=='Microcuff'){
        $("#selectMicrocuff").show();
      $("#selectStandar").hide();
    }

  }//end function
```

in this case i validate the first select(InDiameter), take the value and if is a Standard i show the div that have the select with the options Standard..and etc..
is only a method exist differentes methods.. 
[Verify here](http://jsfiddle.net/eahdwjz3/15/)